# Phonegap HelloWorld not finding WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider

Tags: android, cordova, chromium

I am trying to run the HelloWorld Phonegap project on a Windows 7 32-bit system, running through an Android emulator.  The app immediately crashes and I get a ClassNotFound exception thrown, not finding android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.  Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: Get the same issue. Have you found any solution?